# Laravel Routing Database

Tags: php, database, laravel, routes

I want to save some page information in database with url term that can be shown in URL when that page is going to access via URL. For eg. consider I have a website name as **www.example.com**
now I have page in my site say ***www.example.com/about-us*.**

Now I want to save the details of about us page in database say *title, description and url_name* 
so if I update the content of about us page and set url_name as "**something-about-us**".

When I am accessing link from my website for About Us. so it should redirect to page with URL **www.example.com/something-about-us** *instead of previous url www.example.com/about-us.*

How I can create this kind of database saved routes in Laravel?

Thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: create a `slug` field. then build urls depending upon the slug. like `route('someroute',[$slug])`.... this $slug will be retrieved from the database. so if you update the slug, link will get automatically updated.

Comment: Yes we can do in this way but when I will create this then my route will be Route::get('{slug}',function($slug) { // code from db to show page and redirect to view}). then it will work for www.example.com/about-us as you have suggested, but what about the another route say www.example.com/search that should suppose to call index action of search controller. just because of previous rule is it will call first match route. is it?

Comment: When you add your slug route after the search one, laravel will try to match search first.

Comment: you just needto be careful on route pattern. this `{slug}` will be at the bottom. laravel matches routes from top to bottom.

Comment: Try this

Route::get('{categories}', 'Web\CategoryController@categoryPosts')->where('categories','^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+$')->name('category.pages');

Answer (score 0):

here is my thought. I don't think Laravel provides such a solution to your problem, though not 100% percent.

What you can do is to rewrite your own route file. Firstly, save information about dynamic routes in database and when they are updated, make sure that related database entries are modified accordingly.

Secondly, when requesting for a route, search the database and return url as parameter to redirect.

I am afraid you have to do it yourself just like construct apis using Laravel. If you have any question, I am ready to help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it on this moment... but maybe you can do something like:

```
Route::get('user/{pageid}', function($pageid)
{
    $page_content = //Search DB for page content with url_name = pageid;
    return View::make('page.content', array('page_content' => $page_content));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle URLs in your routes file:

```
    Route::get('{url}', 'PageController@show')
    ->whereIn('url', getUrlsFromDB())
    ->name('dynamicUrls');
```

In helpers.php

```
function getUrlsFromDB()
{
    $urls = Page::pluck('url')
        ->toArray() ?: [];
// maybe strip leading slashes depending on your DB
    foreach ($urls as &$value) {
        $value = substr($value, 1);
    }

    return $urls;
}
```

Routes are typically cached, if you change any urls in the database be sure to do:

```
Artisan::call('route:cache');
```

You could do this in a Model Observers saved method.

In the Models Observers save method you can set up the **Redirect** you want. Maybe you need a seperate model for that.